# SSRS Reports into 4 columns

Tags: reporting-services

I have dataset in the following order

```
Phase  WP    FY     ITEMNO
3C     DS   2016   2007463
3D     DS1  2017   2007463
3E     DS2  2018   2007463
3F     DS3  2019   2007463
3G     DS4  2020   2007463
```

I am trying to make a report in SSRS like this divided into 4 different sections and seperated by a horizontal line

```
2007463

3C     DS   2016      3D     DS1  2017   3E     DS2  2018   3F     DS3  2019  
3G     DS4  2020
```

Comment: Can someone answer what would be the condition or expression or if I need to use a Tablix or matrix report

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a hack but what I would do is

- Add a column number into your dataset that varies from 1 to 4
- Put 4 identical tables on the report horizontally
- Filter each of the tables by the column number

For example, with this dataset I added a column number that varies from 1 to 4 (I also added a few more rows):

```
 WITH cteBase AS (
    SELECT 
        Phase
    ,   WP
    ,   FY
    ,   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Phase) - 1) % 4 + 1 AS ColumnNum
    FROM (VALUES
        ('3C', 'DS', '2016')
    ,   ('3D', 'DS1', '2017')
    ,   ('3E', 'DS2', '2018')
    ,   ('3F', 'DS3', '2019')
    ,   ('3G', 'DS4', '2020')
    ,   ('3H', 'DS5', '2020')
    ,   ('3I', 'DS6', '2020')
    ,   ('3J', 'DS7', '2020')
    ,   ('3K', 'DS8', '2020')
    ) v(Phase, WP, FY)
)

SELECT
    Phase
,   WP
,   FY
,   ColumnNum
FROM cteBase
```

Which gives back your dataset with the included column #

```
Phase   WP  FY  ColumnNum
3C  DS  2016    1
3D  DS1 2017    2
3E  DS2 2018    3
3F  DS3 2019    4
3G  DS4 2020    1
3H  DS5 2020    2
3I  DS6 2020    3
3J  DS7 2020    4
3K  DS8 2020    1
```

Then you create a table for "Column 1", format it however you want, and copy/paste it.  These pasted tables will be for Column 2, 3, and 4.

In each table, set a tablix filter for the appropriate column #.

[image]

This is the preview result

[image]

Edit: If you want this to repeat for each ItemNo...

here is my sample dataset.  Note I changed the Row_Number to partition by ItemNo

```
  WITH cteBase AS (
    SELECT 
        Phase
    ,   WP
    ,   FY
    ,   ItemNo
    ,   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemNo ORDER BY Phase) - 1) % 4 + 1 AS ColumnNum
    FROM (VALUES
        ('3C', 'DS', '2016', '20074063')
    ,   ('3D', 'DS1', '2017', '20074063')
    ,   ('3E', 'DS2', '2018', '20074063')
    ,   ('3F', 'DS3', '2019', '20074063')
    ,   ('3G', 'DS4', '2020', '20074063')
    ,   ('3H', 'DS5', '2020', '20074063')
    ,   ('3I', 'DS6', '2020', '20074063')
    ,   ('3J', 'DS7', '2020', '20074063')
    ,   ('3K', 'DS8', '2020', '20074063')

    ,   ('3C', 'DS', '2016', '99991234')
    ,   ('3D', 'DS1', '2017', '99991234')
    ,   ('3E', 'DS2', '2018', '99991234')
    ,   ('3F', 'DS3', '2019', '99991234')
    ,   ('3G', 'DS4', '2020', '99991234')
    ,   ('3H', 'DS5', '2020', '99991234')
    ,   ('3I', 'DS6', '2020', '99991234')
    ,   ('3J', 'DS7', '2020', '99991234')
    ,   ('3K', 'DS8', '2020', '99991234')
    ) v(Phase, WP, FY, ItemNo)
)

SELECT
    Phase
,   WP
,   FY
,   ItemNo
,   ColumnNum
FROM cteBase
```

Then on the SSRS report, put a List object first.  Make it group by ItemNo.

[image]

Put a textbox in the list to show the ItemNo, then put the tables inside the list.

[image]

Here is the preview

[image]

If you want a page break between each item in the list, select the list, then open the row group properties, go to the Page Breaks section and check the box "Between each instance of a group".

[image]

Comment: I added the columns number into the table. Instead of the list i want to have Itemno's in different pages .Can You please keep snapshots step by step on how I will be able to do that.

Comment: I would still use a list.  Enable the page breaks between each instance of the group.  I updated the answer w/ a new screenshot.